# My Login Method for Access 2007 doesn't work

Tags: vba, authentication, ms-access-2007

This is my first try at VBA on the whole. So I'm not familiar with everything.

I'm trying to make a login for a database in Access 2007.
I have 2 `Tables` named TableLogin and TableUserLevel.
TableLogin has ID, Username, Password and UserLevel that is linked to TableUserLevel.

TableUserLevel has ID and UserLevel which has the levels of Admin and User.
I have a `form` named LoginForm that has 2 fields named txtUsername and txtPassword and a `button` named cmdLogin.

I'm pretty sure my `DLookUp` methods are wrong, but I don't know why. I'm using the first `DLookUp` to see if the username and password match one ID and if so it will then go to the second `DLookUp` method to see which userlevel security that particular user has.

Right now, I'm not sure the first `DLookUp` even works good. I'm not sure if it checks if both input came from one ID. I'm hoping it works like that and the last `DLookUp` method only return `0` and I don't know why.

The VBA code for the button is:

```
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()
    Dim UserLevel As Integer
    Dim Username As String

    If IsNull(Me.txtUsername) Or Me.txtUsername = "" Then
        MsgBox "You must enter a Username.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
        Me.txtUsername.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Check to see if data is entered into the password box

    If IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Or Me.txtPassword = "" Then
        MsgBox "You must enter a Password.", vbOKOnly, "Required Data"
        Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Check value of username and password in tblLogin to see if this

    If IsNull(DLookup("ID", "TableLogin", "Username = '" & Me.txtUsername.Value & "'") And DLookup("ID", "TableLogin", "Password = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'")) Then
        MsgBox "Password or Username invalid. Please Try Again", vbOKOnly, "Invalid Entry!"
    Else
        Username = Me.txtUsername.Value

        If IsNull(DLookup("UserLevel", "TableLogin", "Username = '" & Me.txtUsername.Value & "'")) Then
            MsgBox ("No security level")
        Else
            If UserLevel = 1 Then
                MsgBox ("yes" & UserLevel)
            Else
                MsgBox ("No" & UserLevel)
            End If
        End If

        'Close login form and open screen
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "LoginForm", acSaveNo
    End If

    'If User Enters incorrect password 3 times database will shutdown

    intLogonAttempts = intLogonAttempts + 1
    If intLogonAttempts > 3 Then
        MsgBox "You do not have access to this database. Please contact admin.", vbCritical, "Restricted Access!"
        Application.Quit
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Combine the first 2 `DLookup` expressions like this: `DLookup("ID", "TableLogin", "Username = '" & Me.txtUsername.Value & "'") & " And [Password] = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'")` That single `DLookup` with the compound *Criteria* argument (the third argument) should ensure your name and password matches are found in the same record.

Comment: I bracketed `Password` because it's a reserved word.  Note storing unencrypted passwords in your table would make it almost trivially easy to defeat your security strategy.  It may be OK if all you need is to guide cooperative users through your application features.  But it won't prevent a determined user with moderate Access skills from doing pretty much anything they want with the database.

Comment: @Hans shouldn't it be `unhashed` instead of ùnecrypted`?

Comment: @HansUp I used your expression, but now I'm stuck on error 13: type mismatch. `DLookup("ID", "TableLogin", "Username = ' " & Me.txtUsername.Value & " ' " And " Password = ' " & Me.txtPassword.Value & " ' ")` I don't see where it went wrong. All the data types matches.

Comment: @HansUp **Updated** `DLookup("ID", "TableLogin", "[Username] = '" & Me.txtUsername.Value & "' And  [Password] = '" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'")` Found the problem thank you. It's working now