# Login Form in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

```vb
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim UserLevel As Integer
If IsNull(Me.txtLoginID) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter LoginID", vbInformation, "LoginID Required"
    Me.txtLoginID.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter Password", vbInformation, "Password Required"
    Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
Else
    'process the job

    If (IsNull(DLookup("UserLogin", "tbluser", "UserLogin='" & Me.txtLoginID.Value & "'"))) Or _
    (IsNull(DLookup("UserLogin", "tbluser", "Password='" & Me.txtPassword.Value & "'"))) Then
        MsgBox "Incorrect LoginID or Password"
    Else
        UserLevel = DLookup("UserSecurity", "tbluser", "UserLogin = '" & Me.txtLoginID.Value & "'")
        DoCmd.Close
            If UserLevel = 1 Then
        MsgBox "LoginID and Password correct"
                DoCmd.OpenForm "ali"
        Else
                DoCmd.OpenForm "customer"
        End If
    End If

    End If

End Sub
```

This is code for login form.I have created. When I close my MS Access and open again my project login form cannot work.

Comment: Is this from the same assignment as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061897/my-login-method-for-access-2007-doesnt-work ? -- Also, "cannot work" is not a useful error description. You need to explain what the problem is.

Comment: Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.